# Prevent task being executed again while it is still running

Tags: c#, winforms, task, observablecollection, void

Boys and Girls,

I got this method (task) that gets executed when I select a node in a treeview. It retreives data from a database and puts in a ReportControl (Codejock).

What I need is to prevent that this method (task) gets executed again while it is still running.

I've been experimenting with booleans set to false when starts and set to true if finishes but that doesn't work for some reason.......

here is the code:
the event where the method gets executed:

```
private void tvObjects_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                tvObjects.PreseveTreeState = true;
                tvObjects.SaveTreeState();

                tvObjects.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(191, 210, 234);

                AllowPreview = false;
                WordPreviewer.UnloadPreviewHandler();
                viewer1.Image = null;


                rcDocumenten.ClearContent();
                rcEmail.ClearContent();

                var n = e.Node as ExtendedTreeNode;
                tvObjects.CurrentNode = e.Node;
                SelectedObjectNode = n;
                WordPreviewer.FileName = null;
                if (n != null)
                {
                    Document.SetDossierNummer(n.DossierNr);
                }

                var selNode = e.Node as ExtendedTreeNode;

                if (selNode != null && selNode.DossierNode)
                {
                    if (selNode.IsFolder)
                    {
                        DossierNr = Convert.ToInt32(selNode.DossierNr);

                        SelectedObjectNode = selNode;

                        var col = new col();
                        col.CreateCurrentDossierDocumentsList(Convert.ToInt32(selNode.DossierNr.ToString()),
                                                              selNode.Tag.ToString());
                        col.CreateCurrentEmailList(selNode.DossierNr, Convert.ToInt32(selNode.Tag.ToString()));

                        var t =
                            new Thread(
                                () =>
                                rcDocumenten_Populate(Convert.ToInt32(selNode.DossierNr.ToString()),
                                                      selNode.Tag.ToString()));
                        t.Start();


                        var t2 = new Thread(
                            () => rcEmail_Populate(selNode.DossierNr, Convert.ToInt32(selNode.Tag.ToString())));
                        t2.Start();

                        tcDocumenten.SelectedTab = selNode.Text.Contains("Email") ? tpEmail : tpDocumenten;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tpDocumenten.Text = @"Documenten (0)";
                        tpEmail.Text = @"Emails (0)";

                        SelectedBestandId = -1;
                        SelectedBestandsNaam = string.Empty;
                        SelectedEmailId = -1;
                        SelectedEmailOnderwerp = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                else if (selNode != null && selNode.PersonalNode)
                {
                    if (!selNode.IsMedewerker)
                    {
                        var t =
                        new Thread(
                            () => rcDocumenten_PersoonlijkeMappenPopulate(Convert.ToInt32(selNode.Tag.ToString())));
                        t.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException iex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(iex.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var dmsEx = new DmsException("Fout tijdens het uitvoeren event AfterSelect tvObjects ", "VDocumenten (tvObjects Event: AfterSelect)", ex);
                ExceptionLogger.LogError(dmsEx);
            }

        }
```

the method that should not run twice:

```
    public void rcDocumenten_PersoonlijkeMappenPopulate(int personalFolderId)
        {
            try
            {
                AllowPreview = false;
                var oc = new col();
                rcDocumenten.FocusedRow = null;
                oc.CreateCurrentPersoonlijkeDocumentsList(personalFolderId);
                UpdateUI(false);

                if (rcDocumenten.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    rcDocumenten.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        rcDocumenten.Records.DeleteAll();
                        rcDocumenten.Redraw();

                        _gegevensLaden = new GegevensLaden(this);
                        _gegevensLaden.Show();


                        //Documenten uit Database ophalen



                        _gegevensLaden.progressbar.Maximum = col.ListPersoonlijkeDocuments.Count;

                        foreach (var document in col.ListPersoonlijkeDocuments)
                        {
                            var versie = Convert.ToDecimal(document.Versie.ToString());

                            if (document.OriBestandId == 0)
                            {
                                //Record toevoegen
                                rcDocumenten_Persoonlijk_AddRecord(document.BestandId, document.BestandsNaam, versie,
                                                       document.DatumToevoeg, document.DatumUitcheck, document.UitgechecktDoor, document.Eigenaar,
                                                       document.DocumentType, document.DocumentProgres);
                            }


                            _gegevensLaden.progressbar.Value = _gegevensLaden.progressbar.Value + 1;
                            _gegevensLaden.progressbar.Update();
                        }

                        var aantalRecords = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < rcDocumenten.Records.Count; i++)
                        {
                            aantalRecords++;

                            for (var j = 0; j < rcDocumenten.Records[i].Childs.Count; j++)
                            {
                                aantalRecords++;
                            }
                        }
                        tpDocumenten.Text = @"Documenten (" + aantalRecords + @")";

                        rcDocumenten.Populate();
                        Invoke(new UpdateUIDelegate(UpdateUI), new object[] { true });
                    });
                }
                //"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                AllowPreview = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var dmsEx = new DmsException("Fout bij de populatie van Report Control", "VDocumenten (rcDocumenten_Persoonlijk_Populate)", ex);
                ExceptionLogger.LogError(dmsEx);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can check if the thread/task has completed. Change the thread creation to use a `Task`

```
_t =
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        rcDocumenten_Populate(Convert.ToInt32(selNode.DossierNr.ToString()),
                              selNode.Tag.ToString()));
```

Then you can keep the `Task` around in the class scope. As you see above, I called it `_t`.

```
private Task _t; // documenten vullen achtergrond thread
```

Now, instead of blindly starting the `Task`, check if the `Task` should be started.

```
if (_t == null || _t.IsCompleted) {
```

That would solve your current issue.